# how to get exception if wrong IP used, for python memcache Client

Tags: python, memcached

```
mc = memcache.Client(['111.222.3.2:11211'], debug=1)
```

if wrong ip is used, the client just show debug log.

> MemCached: MemCache: inet:72.18.195.210:11211: connect: Connection refused.  Marking dead.

but I want get a wrong status or an exception. How?

Comment: Which memcache library are you using?

Comment: try `dir(mc)`, there must be some information about what ***mc*** object has...

Comment: thx. python_memcached-1.48-py2.7.egg   i'm trying funcions of dir(mc).

Comment: it seems no exception raised for wrong server ip. i could use servers = mc.get_stats()[0][0] to get an exception. Is it proper?

Comment: i can use:        mc = memcache.Client(mm_server, debug=0)
        if(len(mc.get_stats())==0):
   raise Exception("server not available")

Comment: The library is doing the right thing. Memcached is a cache server and your application should not rely on it to work. It should work without a running memcached server.